# Voice Record on Mobile Web Application

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, mobile-website

**Question:** 
Is it possible, with some sort of technology, to integrate voice recording into a mobile web application?

**Some background:** 
I have been working on a mobile web application just for my own enjoyment and research. Everything seemed to be working pretty slick with HTML5/CSS and JavaScript for the client application, although it looks like I need a third party technology for voice recording. I had a pretty good solution working with Flash, but after testing it with my IPhone, I had remembered that they don't seem to support flash which is disappointing because I had a pretty good solution going.

**Voice Recording Requirements:** 
1. Must work with both iOS and Android. 
2. Must work in most current versions of Firefox, Google Chrome, Internet Explorer, Opera, and Safari. 
3. Must work within the framework of a mobile web application. 
4. Must be able to record without being actively connected to the internet. 
5. The client application shouldn't require the user to alter their phone OS. 

I tried to be as specific as possible to assist in allowing you to answer this question accurately. If anything is unclear, just let me know in a comment below, and I will further clarify.

Comment: You could probably use phone gap for something like this. Check this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305129/with-phonegap-i-would-like-to-record-voice-stop-recording-and-playing-it-in-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like in the years since asking this question a solution has surfaced. This solution has come in the form of MediaStreamConstraints dictionary `audio` property.

The Web API docs from Mozilla have a very nice example shown below:

```
document.getElementById("startButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true
  }).then(stream => audioElement.srcObject = stream)
    .catch(err => log(err.name + ": " + err.message));
}, false);
```

**Resources**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamConstraints/audio

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

**HTML Media Capture `<input type="file">`**

Work for most of the mobile browsers, but it works not well because it will require native recording app and needs to active manually.

**`getUserMedia()` and WebRTC**

So far, only the Chromium support it well in mobile.

**So, I gave up the web app. Hybrid app is the solution.**

If you want to try the hybrid app for recording, you can check the Cordova Plugin https://github.com/emj365/cordova-plugin-audio-recorder-api that I created for recording task in the hybrid app.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to record it as an audio, I think you can only make it for Chrome dev, Chrome canary, Opera next, and some mobile browser.
Using the WebRTC `getUserMedia()` API then make the blob URL of the audio data URL to save it.

If you want to record it as text maybe you can use `<input -x-webkit-speech/>` for webkit browsers. Make an event that make every-time it stop recording it'll add the currently recorded speech to an element and start recording again. Finally, make a blob URL to save it as a text file.